# Splitting a list at a particular position

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it possible to split a list into two lists at a specific position? The main list is for example:

```
data={{xa,ya},{xb,yb},{xc,yc},...,{xz,yz}}.
```

I want to split this list into two new lists:

```
data1={{xa,ya},{xb,yb},...,{xi,yi}}
```

and

```
data2={{xj,yj},{xk,yk},...,{xz,yz}}
```

at a specific y-value at position `i`. I was not successful in using `Part`. Maybe there is another possibility?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be accomplished easily using `Part` (`[[ ]]`) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) (`;;`), as follows:

```
data = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {xz, yz}};
data[[;; 3]]
data[[4 ;;]]

(* ->
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}
{{x4, y4}, {xz, yz}}
*)
```

Comment: You beat me to it, so I added my answer to yours.

Comment: If you don't want `Part[]`, there's always `Take[]`...

Answer (score 7):

Following up on J.M.'s suggestion,

```
m = 3;
data1 = Take[data, m]
data2 = Take[data, -(Length[data] - m)]
```

You might also obtain data2 as follows:

```
data2 = Complement[data, data1]
```

I'm uncertain whether the second approach would maintain order invariant if there are identical sublists.

Comment: Or, perhaps, `{Take[#, 3], Drop[ #, 3]} &@data`

Comment: Surprisingly this is faster than `Part` as recommended by belisarius, and considerably faster than `Take`/`Drop` as recommended by Tom.  It could also be written:  `{Take[data, m], Take[data, {m + 1, -1}]}` with about the same performance.

Comment: I'm surprised it's faster than Take...Drop.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from **10.2** you can use `TakeDrop`

```
data = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {xz, yz}};

{data1, data2} = TakeDrop[data, 3]
(* {{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {{x4, y4}, {xz, yz}}} *)
```